# angular app 404s when navigating with url manually

Tags: angular, iis, url-routing

I've got an Angular 7 website that uses MVC and is hosted on IIS.

Since we're utilizing MVC, we serve up index.html within `_Layout.cshtml` (using `@RenderBody()`) which then uses a controller to serve up `index.cshtml` which houses the `<app-root></app-root>` tags

The app works just fine, however, when trying to navigate to a url manually (e.g. `http://my-site.com/endpoint`) is accessible when using a navigation control, but entering it manually within the address bar, it throws a 404 error.

I keep seeing "Redirect to index.html" but index.html exists within the angular application and isn't a reachable url unless navigating to `http://my-site.com/index.html`.  So how do I serve my endpoint view by redirecting to index.html? How do I even do that?

I've done a fair amount of reading and trying things here on SO, but nothing really matches my issue, and I don't seem to be making any headway.

Let me know if you need to see my code, but from what I read, this needs to be handled on the hosting server.  Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You need to redirect any url to your index.html

Comment: @Ploppy I keep seeing that said, but there doesn't seem to be a clear way to do that. If my application sits on `http://my-site.com` and I need to serve up a view (endpoint in this case), I use `http://my-site.com/endpoint`.  How would index.html be introduced into that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with iis but a quick search led me to this: https://blog.angularindepth.com/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis-60a0897742e7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution to this issue.

If you've got your angular site wrapped in an MVC application, you can setup MVC routes in startup.cs to force any non-MVC route to use the controller/view that serve up the angular application.

This will allow you to navigate to an angular route using a manually entered URL, however it forces a page reload. (for my purposes, this isn't an issue).

below is my code

In `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "mvc",
        template: "{controller}/{action}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are navigating using the nav control you are using the angular router module, but when you type the end point it sounds to me that IIS is looking for this path "outside" of Angular.

Have you tried importing LocationStrategy as a provider and using the HashLocationStrategy in your app.module.ts file?

```
providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass:HashLocationStrategy }
],
```

This strategy will prefix all paths within your Angular application with /#/ and make sure that any # fragments are not sent to the IIS server.

Comment: Although this could work, we need to mask the # in the url.